# Can Provider handle state of a complexed class such as this? If not, how can I make this class available to my entire app in its global state?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like make a Currency object (shown below) shared throughout my entire app using global state (perhaps this isn't the best way?).

I have tried using the Provider package but I cannot seem to get it working.

```
class Currency extends ChangeNotifier {
  String baseCurrency = 'USD';
  Map<String, double> rates = {};
  List<String> currencList = [];

  Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> getLatestCurrencyData() async {
    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper('$url_fixer_io$api_key');
    var currencyData = await networkHelper.getData();

    return currencyData;
  }

  void populateRates() async {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> currencyData = await getLatestCurrencyData();
    Map<String, dynamic> newRates = currencyData['rates'];

    newRates.forEach((curr, rate) {
      this.currencList.add(curr);
      this.rates.putIfAbsent(curr, () => rate.toDouble());
    });

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<List<String>> getCurrencyList() async {
    if (currencList.length == 0) {
      await populateRates();
    }
    return currencList;
  }

  void changeBaseCurrency(String newCurrency) {
    baseCurrency = newCurrency;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The above implementation gives me the following error:

flutter: Another exception was thrown: Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream (Currency).

I have limited experience managing state on reactive platforms such as flutter, and any tips on how I could accomplish this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how complex your class is.
If your class extends ChangeNotifier
Then your class should be made available to the tree by using either

```
ChangeNotifierProvider
```

or

```
ListenableProvider
```

My guess is you were using Provider instead of this two, which has an assertion set to throw if used with Listenable or Stream(ChangeNotifer is Listenable)
This is a portion of code from Provider class

```
 assert((){
 if (value is Listenable || value is Stream) {
    throw FlutterError(''')
```

Instead of Provider use ChangeNotifierProvider or ListenableProvider. The difference is that ChangeNotifierProvider automatically calls the dispose method while you override the dispose method in ListenableProvider